# Helm take it to long to change the STATUS from release to pending-install

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

When I'm installing a new release, helm takes around 5 seconds to change the status to **pending-install**.

E.g. I enter the command *helm install ABC repo/repo-ABC* and in another terminal I enter *helm list -all*, the ABC doesn't appear immediately with the status **pending-install**.

It takes around 5 seconds to change to **pending-install** and then in 10 milliseconds it changes to **deployed**.

It is intended that as I enter the command *helm install*.... the status immediately changes to **pending-install**.

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand the time it takes for those operations are depending on the internet speed, it can take long for the cluster to download the images depending on size (I got here seeking how to increase this time because it is taking too long to download the image so the container fails to start, the image is 7gb, mostly because nvidia's cuda, cudnn and extras are too heavy), when you are dealing with the parts that are done through connections there will be delays and you will have to deal with them, even within your own computer delays occur, you only don't notice, if this happens in a particular repo you could refer to it so people can test it, you also can ask the developers directly in the helm git repository, in my experience most developers are ok with answering questions, I have done questions that can be solved with a comprehensive read of the functions, but many times you just can't find the answer by yourself, here is the git of the helm project https://github.com/helm/helm.